# Can Kafka topic names be parameterised?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, asyncapi

I've recently started experimenting with [AsyncAPI](https://asyncapi.com/) as part of a project at work. My task is to see if we can use AsyncAPI to generate code to send test objects to our existing Kafka queues. I'm not familiar with Kafka.

I'm starting with the API specification at [AsyncAPI playground](https://playground.asyncapi.io/), and trying to generate some Java Spring code from it. However, I've run into an issue in that, in the playground specification, channel names (which will correspond to Kafka topics) are parameterised, e.g. as:

```
smartylighting/streetlights/1/0/event/{streetlightId}/lighting/measured
```

Is it possible to parameterise the Kafka topic in this way, such that the generated service has the following annotation?

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "smartylighting.streetlights.1.0.action.{streetlightId}.lighting.measured", groupId = "myGroupId")
```

Or does this specification (which again, I'm just using to learn AsyncAPI) need to be changed so that topic names are invariant, and instead provide the street light ID as payload data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently one of [missed features](https://github.com/asyncapi/java-spring-template#missing-features) of the java-spring template.

> parameters for topics are not supported

Please consider creation of a new issue with detail description of your case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Async API, but with Spring for Apache Kafka, topic names can contain property placeholders

```
topics = "foo.${some.property}.bar"
```

Where `some.property` is available in the Spring environment e.g. `-Dsome.property` command line or a spring Boot `application.properties` or yaml file.

You can also perform more advanced configuration using the Spring Expression Language.

```
topics = "#{someBean.somePropeerty}"
```

Comment: @Ben R. does tis answer your questions?